# Past perfect tense and definite time adverbs

Tags: tense, adverbs, past-perfect

Example:

Ken lives in city C. My mom and I live in city B.

> > My mom:   Was Ken in city B when we left for city A on 2/15?
> >
> > my first response:    He had already arrived **at the time**.
> >
> > my second response:    He had already arrived **by then**.
> >
> > my third respone:    He had already arrived **on 2/16**.

Which response is grammatically ok?

Can I use a definite time adverb (like yesterday, last month, on 2/16, etc) with past perfect tense when I want to be more specific about what time a past event happened. (of course, on the condition that a past event has been established)

Comment: For the last one, did you mean "... on 2/15", to match your mother's question?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That was a typo. Thank you for your help^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally better to use "by ..." with a past perfect.

You are using a past perfect because you need to refer to a point *before* a given time. So while I understand "He had already arrived on 2/16", I would be more likely to say

> He had already arrived (by 2/16) (by then) (by that time)

If I knew when Ken actually arrived, I'd use simple past

> Yes, he arrived in B city on 2/10.

If I only knew he had arrived some time before, some more details may clarify.

> Yes, I got an email from him on 2/14, so he must have arrived by then.

Or I'd just answer my mum's question:

> Yes. He was already here.